# Problems with Beamer and diagrams in Tikz

Tags: beamer, tikz-matrix

I did a commutative diagram with `tikz` in the article class and everything works.
The next code is the MWE in article class.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,row sep=2em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em]
  { A & B \\
    C & D \\};
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node [above] {e} (m-1-2) edge node [left] {f} (m-2-1)
    (m-1-2) edge node [right] {g} (m-2-2)
    (m-2-1) edge node [below] {h} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

But, when I copy the code in a Beamer document, something is wrong, as the following code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,row sep=2em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em]
  { A & B \\
    C & D \\};
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node [above] {e} (m-1-2) edge node [left] {f} (m-2-1)
    (m-1-2) edge node [right] {g} (m-2-2)
    (m-2-1) edge node [below] {h} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any idea? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With your code you need either to use the `fragile` option for the `frame` or to use the `ampersand replacement` key:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&]
  \matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,row sep=2em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em]
  { A \& B \\
    C \& D \\};
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node [above] {e} (m-1-2) edge node [left] {f} (m-2-1)
    (m-1-2) edge node [right] {g} (m-2-2)
    (m-2-1) edge node [below] {h} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,row sep=2em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em]
  { A & B \\
    C & D \\};
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node [above] {e} (m-1-2) edge node [left] {f} (m-2-1)
    (m-1-2) edge node [right] {g} (m-2-2)
    (m-2-1) edge node [below] {h} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use use [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package to facilitate writing commutative diagrams; in this case, you need to use the `fragile` option for `frame`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
A\arrow{r}{e}\arrow{d}[swap]{f} & B\arrow{d}{g} \\
C\arrow{r}[swap]{h} & D \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do that (add tikz-cd) but still does not work. Actually it does not work if I want to make second column using the & symbol. Any ideas?