# Beamer Tikz-cd Problem

Tags: beamer, diagrams, tikz-cd

I have a problem with `tikz-cd`. When I try to compile in `beamer` it doesn't work and I no have idea why. Can someone help-me, please?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{
  every picture/.prefix style={
    execute at begin picture=\shorthandoff{"}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
\section{Motivation}

\begin{frame}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
Y \ar[dr, "\displaystyle{p_G}"'] \ar[rr, "\displaystyle{p}"]& &  X \\
& Aut(Y|X)\bs Y \ar[ur, "\displaystyle{\widetilde{p}_G}"'] &
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try with `\begin{frame}[fragile]` instead of just `\begin{frame}`. It worked for me if I suppress `\bs` (which I don't know what it means, because I've never used `tikz-cd`)

Comment: It doesn't work, but thanks you Harish!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I get with your code when option `[fragile]` is used after frame and command `\bs` is supressed:

I could not find a reference to `\bs` command in `tikz-cd` documentation and I deleted it because compilation stopped there.

[image]

The modified code is

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{
  every picture/.prefix style={
    execute at begin picture=\shorthandoff{"}
  }
}

\listfiles %<----- Add to get packages version list in .log file
\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
\section{Motivation}

\begin{frame}[fragile] %<-----------------------
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
Y \ar[dr, "\displaystyle{p_G}"'] \ar[rr, "\displaystyle{p}"]& &  X \\
& Aut(Y|X) Y \ar[ur, "\displaystyle{\widetilde{p}_G}"'] &
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And packages versions are following. Please compare them with your results and update your system if necessary.

```
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2013/12/02 3.33 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revi
sion 332bfd3ce558)
beamerbasercs.sty    2013/12/25 (rcs-revision 31cc758a62ae)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2013/09/03 (rcs-revision 768f2d98ca64)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
beamerbaseoptions.sty    2013/03/10 (rcs-revision 47431932db0d)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbasefont.sty    2013/10/18  (rcs-revision 72f39e01808a)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    2013/09/03  (rcs-revision a55719c41d85)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2013/12/25  (rcs-revision f6bd5e3805da)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/09/21  (rcs-revision f0446ed0b6ae)
beamerbasesection.sty    2013/06/07  (rcs-revision 60b9fe0f342f)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2013/10/02  (rcs-revision cdc8e9a3aaac)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2012/08/30  (rcs-revision dfdb135076b3)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2013/10/18  (rcs-revision 5cf6c5555a45)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision d1a9b48be06d)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2013/05/23  (rcs-revision 0fdf5bc43be8)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2013/09/04  (rcs-revision 4ac715c499d0)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2012/05/13  (rcs-revision 56972908a390)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2013/09/04  (rcs-revision 4ac715c499d0)
enumerate.sty    1999/03/05 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2013/10/05  (rcs-revision 62be157fe783)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2009/07/02 v2.20.1
beamerbasethemes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    2013/10/15  (rcs-revision 65cb471f9634)
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerthemeWarsaw.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerinnerthemerounded.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemeshadow.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemesplit.sty    2012/10/16  (rcs-revision 51a8c72084af)
beamercolorthemeorchid.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemewhale.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemeserif.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
   babel.sty    2014/09/25 3.9l The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
portuges.ldf    2008/03/18 v1.2q Portuguese support from the babel system
 tikz-cd.sty    2014/03/08 v0.9b Commutative diagrams with tikz
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
  211744.out
  211744.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
  211744.vrb
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
```

Answer (score 40):

Instead of using the `fragile` option to beamer's `frame` (which might cause other things to malfunction), it is safer to use the `ampersand replacement` option of `tikzcd`. See also [Problems with Beamer and diagrams in Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119870/problems-with-beamer-and-diagrams-in-tikz) and the section “Issues with active ampersand­­” in the `tikz-cd` manual.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \[
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&, column sep=small]
            Y \ar[dr, "\displaystyle{p_G}"'] \ar[rr, "\displaystyle{p}"] \& \&  X \\
            \& Aut(Y|X) Y \ar[ur, "\displaystyle{\widetilde{p}_G}"'] \&
        \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note the `\&` for cell separation.

Comment: This worked for me.