# Keep getting missing $ error in beamer using code that worked fine elsewhere

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-cd

I am getting errors like, missing $ inserted or extra or forgotten } while trying to compile the following code using beamer class.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand*{\theorembreak}{\usebeamertemplate{theorem end}\framebreak\usebeamertemplate{theorem begin}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usetheme{Warsaw}``
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}[font=\small]
0 \ar{r} & \frac{E'(K)}{\phi(E(K))} \ar{r}{\delta} \ar{d} 
    & H^{1}(G_K, E[\phi]) \ar{r} \ar{d}{Res_v} & WC(E/K)[\phi] \ar{r} \ar{d} & 0 \\
0 \ar{r} & \frac{E'(K_v)}{\phi(E(K_v))} \ar{r}{\delta_{v}} \ar{d} 
    & H^{1}(G_{v}, E[\phi]) \ar{r} \ar{d} & WC(E/K_{v})[\phi] \ar{r} \ar{d} & 0 \\
0 \ar{r} & \prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}} \frac{E'(K_v)}{\phi(E(K_v))} 
            \ar{r}{\prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}}\delta_{v}} 
    &
\prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}} H^{1}(G_{v}, E[\phi]) \ar{r} &
\prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}} WC(E/K_{v})[\phi] \ar{r} & 0
\end{tikzcd}  
    \end{equation}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Specifically, I get the following message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options 

l.23 \end{frame}
```

If I type `r` and hit return, LaTeX reports lots of errors, spits out "That makes 100 errors; please try again." and crashes.

I have used the same code in another LaTeX document where it worked fine. But so I think the error could be some missing package. I don't know..

Can someone help me figure this out?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. I've added a bit more information about the errors that LaTeX produces. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error goes away if one adds `fragile` to the `frame` options. But then one still has to adjust some widths to make it fit on a frame. One possible way is to set the `column sep` to `1em` but increase the distance between the second and third column to `2em` by adding `[2em]` in the third column. (I also added the `t` option because I like this better and dropped the equation number to save some space and since in presentations it is in general not too useful to have them, but like everything here these are just suggestions.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand*{\theorembreak}{\usebeamertemplate{theorem end}\framebreak\usebeamertemplate{theorem begin}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{A commutative diagram}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[font=\small,column sep=1em]
0 \ar{r} &\frac{E'(K)}{\phi(E(K))} \ar{r}{\delta} \ar{d} 
    &[2em]  H^{1}(G_K, E[\phi]) \ar{r} \ar{d}{Res_v} & WC(E/K)[\phi] \ar{r} \ar{d} & 0 \\
0 \ar{r} & \frac{E'(K_v)}{\phi(E(K_v))} \ar{r}{\delta_{v}} \ar{d} 
    & H^{1}(G_{v}, E[\phi]) \ar{r} \ar{d} & WC(E/K_{v})[\phi] \ar{r} \ar{d} & 0 \\
0 \ar{r} & \prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}} \frac{E'(K_v)}{\phi(E(K_v))} 
            \ar{r}{\prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}}\delta_{v}} 
    &
\prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}} H^{1}(G_{v}, E[\phi]) \ar{r} &
\prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}} WC(E/K_{v})[\phi] \ar{r} & 0
\end{tikzcd}  
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of adding `fragile` you can add an `ampersand replacement`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand*{\theorembreak}{\usebeamertemplate{theorem end}\framebreak\usebeamertemplate{theorem begin}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A commutative diagram}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[font=\small,column sep=1em,ampersand replacement=\&]
0 \ar{r} \&\frac{E'(K)}{\phi(E(K))} \ar{r}{\delta} \ar{d} 
    \&[2em]  H^{1}(G_K, E[\phi]) \ar{r} \ar{d}{Res_v} \& WC(E/K)[\phi] \ar{r} \ar{d} \& 0 \\
0 \ar{r} \& \frac{E'(K_v)}{\phi(E(K_v))} \ar{r}{\delta_{v}} \ar{d} 
    \& H^{1}(G_{v}, E[\phi]) \ar{r} \ar{d} \& WC(E/K_{v})[\phi] \ar{r} \ar{d} \& 0 \\
0 \ar{r} \& \prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}} \frac{E'(K_v)}{\phi(E(K_v))} 
            \ar{r}{\prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}}\delta_{v}} 
    \&
\prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}} H^{1}(G_{v}, E[\phi]) \ar{r} \&
\prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}} WC(E/K_{v})[\phi] \ar{r} \& 0
\end{tikzcd}  
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Both the `fragile` and `ampersand replacement` options have been proposed in many posts, such as the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211774/194703).