# Beamer and tikz-cd

Tags: beamer, tikz-cd

The answers here have helped me get the PDF to asctually compile, but the product is not what I need just yet [Beamer Tikz-cd Problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211774/beamer-tikz-cd-problem)

I am trying to produce this diagram, which compiles just fine in my thesis, just not in beamer

[image]

which in the thesis has the code

```
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]
    \large{\text{Poincaré}} \arrow[r,"\text{C}"] \arrow[rd, red, "\text{E} \hspace{1 em}\circ\hspace{1 em} \text{C}"'] & \large{\text{Galilei}} \arrow[d,"\text{E}"] \\
     & \large{\text{Bargmann}}
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
```

In the beamer, I followed some suggestions from the above Stack answer but so far I only have

[image]
with the following code

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,sep=huge]
    \large{\text{Poincaré}} \arrow[r,"\text{C}"] \arrow[rd, red, "\text{E} \hspace{1 em}\circ\hspace{1 em} \text{C}"'] \& \large{\text{Galilei}} \arrow[d,"\text{E}"] \\
     \& \large{\text{Bargmann}}
  \end{tikzcd}
  \]
```

and the following errors

[image]

Comment: `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{\dots}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,sep=huge]
    \text{\large{Poincar\'e}} \arrow[r,"\text{C}"] 
 \arrow[rd, red, "\text{E} \hspace{1 em}\circ\hspace{1 em} \text{C}"'] 
 \& \text{\large{Galilei}} \arrow[d,"\text{E}"] \\
     \& \text{\large{Bargmann}}
  \end{tikzcd}
  \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}` compiles without error. Can you please provide a minimal document that shows the problems?

Comment: From the error message I suppose that you need `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` in the preamble. That is, you probably load the `babel` package, and since `tikz-cd` is loading and using the `quotes` library, you also need the `babel` Ti*k*Z library.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I have put `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead of `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`.

Comment: @Sebastiano Well, do you reproduce the OP's error messages if you remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`? Probably not. So presumably this does not fix the problem. (Please do not get me wrong, I am also guessing, but since the OP uses `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` in other codes, and since adding `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` allows me to reproduce the error messages, I feel that there is a chance that my guess is correct.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I have deleted my answer. :-).

Comment: @Sebastiano I did not mean to suggest that you delete your answer, I was only suggesting changes so that others feel more comfortable upvoting it.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat thank you very much. In the meanwhile I'm working for my school. I am very tired :-(

Comment: OOOOO I see! I had no idea that babel would effect tikz! Thank you both so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the suggestion of the very nice user Schrödinger's cat.....

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,sep=huge]
\text{\large Poincaré}\arrow[r,"\text{C}"] \arrow[rd, red, "\text{E} \hspace{1 em}\circ\hspace{1 em} \text{C}"'] \& \large{\text{Galilei}} \arrow[d,"\text{E}"] \\
     \& \large{\text{Bargmann}}
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFLFV.png]