# Beamer and tikz commutative diagram

Tags: beamer, errors, tikz-cd

I am trying to insert a commutative diagram in my beamer with tikz-cd but this does not work. I think there is some conflict with other things in the beamer but I can't figure out what is happening. Even this very simple code does not compile.

Here is a non minimal example: I show every package I use for you to see if there is something wrong.

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathabx, amssymb}
\usepackage{caption, subfig}
\usepackage{pifont, tikz, tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\definecolor{my}{RGB}{0,51,38}
\usetheme{boadilla}
\usecolortheme[named=my]{structure}
\useoutertheme{split}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\[
\begin{tikzcd} A\arrow[r] & B\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The returned error is the following: ! Undefined control sequence.
 \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options

l.434 \end{frame}

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please make sure your example is self contained, that theme is know a known theme. At least it does not seem to be in TeXLive 2020

Comment: Add the `[fragile]` option to the frame and it compiles just fine. For example seen here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211948/3929

Comment: Off-topic: (i) more correct is `\documentclass[xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames}]{beamer}`, (ii) `beamer` has own mechanism for captions which doesn't work well with ˙caption`.