# tikz-cd "undefined control sequence"

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I cut-and-paste a basic example from the tikzcd manual and keep getting error messages.  Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  $$
  \begin{tikzcd}
%    \\
    & C
  \end{tikzcd}
  $$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This example works, BUT if uncomment the \ line I get the error message

```
\pgf@matrix@no@eom@found ->\cr 
                               \noalign {\vskip \pgf@y \ifpgf@matrix@fixed \...
l.14 \end{frame}
```

And if I keep hitting "return" on these errors messages, I get more and different ones:

```
? 
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.13 \end{frame}
                
? 
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.13 \end{frame}
                
? 
! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.13 \end{frame}
                
? 
! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 
                    
l.13 \end{frame}
```

The code is taken from the manual so I'm confused.  In case this matters, I am using TexLive 2017/Debian.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Better use `\[ ... \]` instead of `$$ ... $$` ([learn why](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/47927)). And then, [according to this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211774/47927), using `\begin{frame}[fragile]` should help

Comment: With a recent installation of TeXlive, your sample code gives no errors. What does the log file say about versions? Mine says: `pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021)`, `LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1`, `tikz-cd 2021/05/04 v1.0`

Comment: @habicht:  \begin{frame}[fragile]  solves the problem!   Thanks!  What does this do?

Comment: @gernot:   My texlive says     This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded
 format=pdflatex 2019.7.13)  26 JAN 2022 13:00    (and how do you "shade" a line of text?  I tried "Ctrl-L" to no avail)

Comment: Updating (La)TeX probably solves your problem. For the shading, enclose the text in backticks `\``

Answer (score 5):

You have two possibilities that I'll show in two different frames.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
   A \arrow[r] \& B \arrow[d]\\
   \& C
  \end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\[
  \begin{tikzcd}
   A \arrow[r] & B \arrow[d]\\
   & C
  \end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The first way is more efficient, but a bit annoying; the second way is slower because it requires writing to a file an inputting it.

[image]

Why the need for `ampersand replacement=\&`? Because when a non `fragile` frame code is read in, you're actually passing the contents as the argument to a command and `tikz-cd` then requires the trick. In the `fragile` case, the frame code is input from a file so it's not regarded as the argument to a command.

Two more comments: never use `$$` in LaTeX. Also `latin1` is really obsolete: save your files in UTF-8 and you'll be happier.

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately the first solution gives the same error message.  Also, when I replace  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   with  \usepackage[UTF-8]{inputenc}  I got the error message "LaTeX Error: File `UTF-8.def' not found."

Comment: @underflow Saver your files as UTF8 and forget about `inputenc`. About the error, I can say nothing: I don't get it.