Overleaf beamer suggestion to compile code
What command do I use to compile the following code? Thank you very much
\[\begin{tikzcd} [cells={nodes={draw=black, circle}}]
    &&& {v_3} \arrow["a_2"', no head, loop, distance=2em, in=125, out=55, color={rgb,255:red,92;red,92;red,214} ]\\
    {v_1} &&&&& {v_5} \\
    && {v_2} && {v_4}
    \arrow["{a_4}", color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=2-1, to=1-4]
    \arrow["{a_3}"', color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=3-3, to=3-5]
    \arrow["{a_1}", color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, curve={height=-12pt}, no head, from=2-1, to=3-3]
    \arrow["{a_5}", color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, curve={height=-12pt}, no head, from=3-3, to=2-1]
\end{tikzcd}\]


The offending code appears to be curve={height=-12pt}, when compiled with tikz and tikz-cd.

there is nothing overleaf related in this question, overleaf hosts a standard texlive distribution and you would get the same output from any tex installation.

@Tomais Can you please show what you tried so we can see if the problem is only the wrong curve to name or if your question is actually a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211774/beamer-tikz-cd-problem ?

Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete  document that shows the problem.

Given the answer by the OP, fixing the curve error does not seem the aim of the OP, so this seem to be indeed a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211774/beamer-tikz-cd-problem

Did you mean to use curve to= instead of just curve=?
I decided to post this as an answer rather than as a comment, so the question could have a preamble and be slightly easier to read/debug.
Edited to be in beamer with a fragile frame, per comment section.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
    \[
        \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=black, circle}}]
            &&& {v_3} 
            \arrow[
                "a_2"'
                ,no head
                ,loop
                ,distance=2em
                ,in=125
                ,out=55
                ,color={rgb,255:red,92;red,92;red,214} 
            ]\\
            {v_1} &&&&& {v_5} \\
            && {v_2} && {v_4}
            \arrow[
                "{a_4}"
                ,color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}
                ,no head
                ,from=2-1
                ,to=1-4
            ]
            \arrow[
                "{a_3}"'
                ,color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}
                ,no head
                ,from=3-3
                ,to=3-5
            ]
            \arrow
            [
                "{a_1}", color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}
                ,curve to={height=-12pt}
                ,no head
                ,from=2-1
                ,to=3-3
            ]
            \arrow[
                "{a_5}"
                ,color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}
                ,curve to={height=-12pt}
                ,no head
                ,from=3-3
                ,to=2-1
            ]
        \end{tikzcd}
    \]
    \end{frame}
\end{document}


Again, per @samcarterisattopanswers.xyz's comment, you could use "ampersand replacement=..." to choose another character instead of &, which will avoid errors in non-fragile beamer frames.

Maybe note that with the class used by the OP, this either needs a fragile frame of an ampersand replacement

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I see that the post encloses the tikzcd in \[\], so it would probably have been better to use article or other. Pardon if I have any misconceptions here, but aren't fragile frames from beamer? Is there something in the OP's post that indicates they are using beamer? Also, again please pardon any lack of insight, by ampersand replacement, do you mean that various rows do not currently have enough? Thank you for your time.

The question title mentions beamer.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I completely missed that! Sorry about that. I will edit the post.

With ampersand replacement, I mean the tikzcd option "ampersand replacement=..." to choose another character instead of &, which will avoid errors in non-fragile beamer frames.

I was able to compile with my original code and your help.
Thank you very much

Even if overleaf is hiding them well, you should never ignore error messages.
